# What will be a good way to test non react components used in ReactJS?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

What will be a good way to test non react components in ReactJS. We currently use Enzymes but that is limited to react components. What will be a good way to unit test non react components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Enzyme's Github page:

*"Enzyme is unopinionated regarding which test runner or assertion library you use, and should be compatible with all major test runners and assertion libraries out there. The documentation and examples for enzyme use mocha and chai, but you should be able to extrapolate to your framework of choice."*

Pretty sure you can test any sort of javascript with Enzyme, just don't use the constructs built into Enzyme that were made for Enzyme, or even better use assertion libraries that you need for your non-react components.

EDIT: Some caveats you might run into, but there are solutions for them https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/278

Comment: Thanks for the caveats comment.Thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Test as you would normally do. Enzyme does not have a test runner or assertion framework. If you are using Mocha and Chai, then write tests with Mocha and Chai as you would normally do.